# SQL Server - Insert only if TRY_CAST is successful, if not do nothing

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do insert into with a select that has a `CAST()`:

```
INSERT INTO table1 
  (table1_Numeric_Value)
SELECT
  TRY_CAST(e.text_found AS float) 
FROM
  Event AS e
```

The problem is if `TRY_CAST()` fails, then the whole insert is beeing stopped. Is there any way to make it insert only if the `TRY_CAST()` is successful?

Answer (score 2):

Just put a condition in the `WHERE` clause:

```
INSERT INTO table1 
  (table1_Numeric_Value)
SELECT
  TRY_CAST(e.text_found AS float) 
FROM
  Event AS e
WHERE
  TRY_CAST(e.text_found AS float) IS NOT NULL
```

(The server *should* be intelligent enough to only perform the conversion once)

---

Just for completeness, here's how to write the query if you want *any* failed conversions to prevent *all* rows from being inserted:

```
declare @t table (
    text_value varchar(30)
)
declare @u table (
    val float
)

insert into @t(text_value) values ('1.0'),('def'),('2.0')

insert into @u(val)
select Val from (
select
    TRY_CAST(text_value as float) as Val,
    COUNT(*) OVER() as Cnt1,
    COUNT(TRY_CAST(text_value as float)) OVER() as Cnt2
from @t
) t
where Cnt1 = Cnt2
```

Comment: This looks very clever. In case of NULL, would it "ignore" the row that causes that NULL or the whole insert completely?

Comment: It filters out those rows that fail the conversion. If you want *no* rows inserted if *any* rows fail than we have a bit more work to do - please edit your question to make that clear if its so.

Comment: No, I am after a way to make it insert anything that doesn't fail

Comment: Use a simple where condition in this case

Answer (score 1):

Either filter out all NULL values using a where condition.

```
INSERT INTO table1 
  (table1_Numeric_Value)
SELECT
  TRY_CAST(e.text_found AS float) AS table1_Numeric_Value
FROM
  Event AS e
WHERE
  TRY_CAST(e.text_found AS float) IS NOT NULL
```

or you can transform NULL values to any value you chose using ISNULL or COALESCE:

```
INSERT INTO table1 
  (table1_Numeric_Value)
SELECT
  COALESCE(TRY_CAST(e.text_found AS float), 0) AS table1_Numeric_Value
FROM
  Event AS e
```

The result of the above two queries might be different, chose based on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can  use `ISNUMERIC` function and filter out any null values. I guess u have string characters in data. Check this query before inserting, this will ensure no rows with `string` characters will be selected

```
SELECT
  TRY_CAST(e.text_found AS float) 
FROM
  Event AS e where ISNUMERIC(e.text_found) = 1--- Selects rows with numeric 
                                                               values
  and e.text_found is not null
```